# Joomla. Editor add tags with css rules inside, i want just tags!

Tags: css, templates, joomla, tags, editor

I encountered a problem:
SEO guys in my company said, that one of our web sites (cms - joomla) have bad html formating at articles- like  and they want to see it like  and new css rules for .newclass in css file! Question: can i change settings in joomla editor for short tags without any css inside?

Answer (score 0):

In general, the problem is not the editor, it is the way your content is being added to the site. Most people copy and paste content in to the editor. What you don't see is that by default your computer tries to preserve the formatting. Both Windows and OSX write really crappy inline CSS that is added behind the scenes. Your best bet is to paste everything in as plain text. I use the JCE editor on every site I do and it has a paste option to paste everything in as plain text so that all of the ugly formatting is stripped out. Pasting content in this way should fix your issue.